# Unable to use Google Play Services Vision in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-vision

I am devloping an Android application in Eclipse which can scan Bar codes and QR codes.

I unzipped the google-play-services aar file, renamed the classes.jar and added it to my project libs folder. The code compiled but I got runtime errors saying NoClassDefFoundError. I think there is a mistake in linking.

I looked for ZXing. But for Zxing to work, the BarcodeScanner App has to be installed in the phone which I don't want. I want to scan the code in my app itself. So, I have to use Google Play Services Vision API.

So, can anybody send the correct jar file or tell me how to modify the properties of project to use the classes.jar or tell the correct procedure to include the aar file in my eclipse project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Barcode Scanning, Options? Zxing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607858/android-barcode-scanning-options-zxing)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am not asking which library should I use. I am asking the correct way to use the play-services-vision aar file in my eclipse project.

Comment: Are you aware that [Eclipse is no longer officially supported for Android Development](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html). Using Eclipse may be preventing you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project. It may be the caused why you are unable to use the Google Play Service. To migrate to the Android Studio from Eclipse just follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) from Google developers.