# Can ZXing be used in Android with encrypted QR-codes?

Tags: android, aes, qr-code, zxing

The current method uses AES encrypted files.
The goal is to exchange small amounts of private data using AES encrypted [QR-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app).

Comment: I think this is VERY cool stuff. Are you building a framework or library for this?

Comment: If it becomes a must have for my project, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as an encrypted QR code as far the spec is concerned. In that sense, no.

However you can in theory put whatever bytes you want in a QR code. Those bytes could happen to be the encrypted version of some data. It would not make sense to most readers as it is a custom, non-standard use of QR codes.

But you can easily modify an encoder/decoder to do this on Android, yes.