# BarCode Rearder Zxing

Tags: android

I want to Scan QR codes on button Click, problem is when I run code on my device Activity Result Intent variable always returns 0.

How do I know if the barcode reader work? I currently see yellow dots on the device's screen.

Here is my code:

```
private OnClickListener scanner = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(BarCodeScannerActivity.this);
    }
}; 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
     if (scanResult != null) {
           // handle scan result
           String s = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
           s += scanResult.getContents();

           Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(s));
           startActivity(myIntent1);
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at this, you probably need to add more parameters to initiateScan: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4714083/67566

Comment: I do this without using IntentIntegrator, so not certain the best approach with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in code

You should have

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (result != null) {
      String contents = result.getContents();
      if (contents != null) {
        showDialog(R.string.result_succeeded, result.toString());
      } else {
        showDialog(R.string.result_failed, getString(R.string.result_failed_why));
      }
    }
  }
```

You are not overriding the `onActivityResult` like `onCreate` or `onStart`

Rather you are writing onActivityResult like normal method which is most common mistake.

Also if you can mention `integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);` or `integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);` it would be great.

Comment: integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);  is giving error it accept only Activity name

Comment: I was going mad over this, and then came your post about the `@Overrride`, great help, and the `initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);` works fine, but remember that it does not return anything when you provide a parameter