# How to read from barcode scanner

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I have an `Activity` where the user can read some barcodes with a barcode scanner (think on it like a hardware keyboard), which sends a string (usually full of numbers) and a CR symbol at the end (an "enter", we could say). When I read this CR symbol, I have to open a `dialog` and do some stuff on it with the received string.

The questions are:

- How can I listen the string received form the barcode scanner without writing it on an `EditText`? I mean, since the barcode scanner is like a hardware keyboard, writing the string on a hidden `EditText` and then listen for the CR symbol could be a solution, but there has to be a more elegant way...
- How can I listen to the CR symbol and how could I difference it from the string full of numbers?

I've taken a look at the [Handling Keyboard Actions tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html), but I think it doesn't fit my needs.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not read it into a string and then process the string? Post some code so we can help.

Comment: How could I read it in a string? Any example?

Comment: I don't have any code related yet, sorry. I'm thinking about how to do it before coding it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Zxing library: https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

This might help as well, you notice some example storing the results in a string for processing:
[How to read barcodes with the camera on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443891/how-to-read-barcodes-with-the-camera-on-android)