# Android unable to execute dex

Tags: android

I am beginning to work on an android app with a group that has already started. After installing the SDK, and running the emulator, I got these error when trying to run the code.

> [2012-02-02 19:59:45 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/swipe/DrawView;
>   [2012-02-02 19:59:45 - SwipeActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/swipe/DrawView;

EDIT:
I have been trying everything in the link provided. I uninstalled the SDK and Eclipse ADT and now I get this error when reinstalling.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
  Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364) requires

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have updated your Eclipse trough Help->Check for updates and istall the latest updates and if you use Windows make sure to do this with administrator rights.
If that doesn't work, you could also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7884908/1084764

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `android-support-v4.jar` libs file in the project. And then cleaning your project. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `eclise.ini`:

```
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, If you have added google-play-service library project. Then just Update it revision from SDK Manager.

Please verify it and let me know if any one not able to resolve it.