# HttpClient from apache in Android?

Tags: java, android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I already have developed an desktop application using Java and now I need to develop the same application to Android.
In my java application I've used the httpclient library from apache to make all http transactions, my question is: Can I use the same class HttpUtil that I've used in my java application with HttpClient in my new Android app ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Much, most, or all of your code can work in Android. Just make sure to continue using the Apache imports and not Google's (near) equivalents.

For example, instead of:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
```

Make sure you continue to use this:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible look what I'm getting when I try to run my android application: [2013-03-21 11:35:13 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;
[2013-03-21 11:35:13 - TargetAppAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;

Comment: It appears to be a compile issue that may involve clean/refresh or tools update. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray/7884908#7884908 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122377/android-unable-to-execute-dex.

Comment: You were right. I was importing HttpClient lib, but it is available in Android default libs, my mistake.