# Unable to have signed .apk file from Eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to upload my app in market place. for this i have tried to generate signed .apk file.
I have followed these step:
project>android tools> export signed application package
a window appears i have created new keystore in a new folder by giving location and password. keystore is successfully saved then i move forward, give alias details then gave  path to the  same folder where the keystore is present for .apk file. But the error i got is:

```
[2012-09-09 10:34:03 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define   Lorg/project/R$attr;
```

In my project workspace, bin folder i have found classes.dex file. I deleted that file then again repeated the same process but the error is same. When i deleted R file and regenerate it by clean the project. classes.dex again created. how to get rid of such error and have signed .apk?

Kindly help me. I will be very thankful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Answer (score 0):

```
select project,click left.
select export
Select Project Name,click next
Create new key keystore
in Location,select location & file name name.apk
Give password & confirm Password
Fill alias,retype password,confirm password,validity at least 25
in below fields,fill atleast 1;
click next,
select location for apk& name of apk with .apk

This apk is signed & zipalin.

Read Link 
**http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html**
Heading
**Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT**
```

Comment: The error is come in pop up window. Still the error message is same:( Is there any technical issue???  what to do with dex file? I can't remove it.