# Android: Dex conversion failed while importing

Tags: android, dex

I got an error while i import an android project from one workspace location to another in eclipse.

I'm using Google_admob in my project to display ads..I does't have any errors and it works well in my old workspace.

**Eclipse Version** : Indigo Service Release 2

**Android-Project Version :** Android 4.0.3

**Error states :** 
[2012-12-03 12:02:27 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/Ad;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/Ad;

[image]

Comment: may be it will helpful to you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: Got it raju..thanks..i explained my solution below

Comment: dont forgot to accept if you got solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found my problem.

I actually import my lib jar file in libs_folder and also in project_libraries(External Jar)..So 2 times dex file has created in **bin/dexedLibs/** ..Now i deleted one jar file from one location ..

now its working

Thanks for your support geeks..

Answer (score 2):

My problem was resolved after cleaning up some directories and files left over from the previous versions of the tools. [ADT Rev 14 changes where binaries are stored](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14). I deleted the entire bin directory, restarted Eclipse and cleaned the build and forced a rebuild. That seemed to do the trick initially but the problem came back after the next run.

I finally discovered that my bin directory was included in the project build path. I excluded bin from the build path and repeated the steps above. This resolved my problem.