# JSON Serializer Android

Tags: android, jsonserializer, json-lib

I am using JSONLib 2.4 for the JSONSerializer() method. Every time I start the activity it force closes. I tried throwing a JSONException, but it gave me an error. What's wrong? This is the call:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);
```

Here's my LogCat output:

01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/sf/json/JSONException; (1034)
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): Link of class 'Lnet/sf/json/JSONException;' failed
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 813 (Lnet/sf/json/JSONException;)
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2e
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): VFY:  rejected Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;.toJSON (Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/json/JsonConfig;)Lnet/sf/json/JSON;
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002e
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): VFY:  rejected Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;.toJSON (Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/json/JsonConfig;)Lnet/sf/json/JSON;
01-14 17:29:24.825: W/dalvikvm(13265): Verifier rejected class Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;
01-14 17:29:24.856: W/dalvikvm(13265): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b28930)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sf/json/JSONSerializer
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at com.aer.illbehonest.VideoPlay$ShowTitlesTask.doInBackground(VideoPlay.java:63)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at com.aer.illbehonest.VideoPlay$ShowTitlesTask.doInBackground(VideoPlay.java:1)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-14 17:29:24.872: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    ... 4 more

Comment: Whats the value of `jsonTxt`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the first line of the logcat.

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/sf/json/JSONException
```

If you look at the [javadoc for JSONException](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONException.html) it shows the class hierarchy. You can see just above JSONException it says `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException` which means that NestableRuntimeException is the superclass of JSONException, and therefore you need to have NestableRuntimeException in your project in order for JSONException to work.

In the same way that you added JsonLib to your project, you should also add the dependencies of JsonLib.  According to mvnrepository, json-lib 2.4 depends on quite a view libraries, with commons-lang 2.5 being one of them.  You can see them as reported by mvnrepository [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4).  You can also see them listed on the json-lib project page [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html).

For a mobile application that seems like a large number of dependencies and will make your apk bigger. I've not used json-lib, but I might suggest using something more self-contained like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ([download](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)).

Comment: Please don't think me to be an idiot, but can you give me an example of what you mean? I'm still a beginner with Java.

Comment: Everyone's a beginner at some point. I updated the answer, hopefully you find it more helpful.

Comment: I did that and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: It won't let me put it in try/catch... isn't that what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Ok, updated again with more information about the versions and an alternate json library.  You could also use Jackson, which is my preferred json library, but it's also bigger than gson.

Comment: This worked for, but now i'm getting this error: Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/collections/Buffer;

Comment: Hi, I just found an workaround for my problem above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray