# Android Eclipse Multiple Dex Files Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dex

I have been getting this error when trying to launch my android project, it didn't happen before, and started to happen randomly.  I didn't even update anything between when it was working and now.  The error is:

```
[2013-01-24 18:06:28 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opendatakit/sensors/AbstractSensorDriverDiscovery;
[2013-01-24 18:06:28 - opendatakit.sensors] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opendatakit/sensors/AbstractSensorDriverDiscovery;
```

I know people have experienced this problem before, but most of the issues I have seen were from over a year ago, typically dealing with ADT r14.  I am using Eclipse 4.3.0 with ADT r17.  I have not seen anyone dealing with these problems with these versions.  Has this been solved by anyone?

The other solutions I have seen, in posts like [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray?rq=1), have not been of any use to me.

If anyone has any advice on the subject I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the error to this problem after much heartache.  For some reason, a global folder had been included in my project and was being built into my project each time.  This folder contained the same jar that I had in my libs folder and that was causing a conflict.

If anyone else has this problem, ensure you only have one jar file in the project.