# Android application using Eclipse. classpath conflicts (Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define)

Tags: android, eclipse, classpath, conflict

I used a classpath checker and as a result it showed that additional.jar(from email library) and droidText0.2.jar (converting pdf) has a the same classpath. Can anyone please help me with this? I have been stuck for the last 2 weeks and I just could not find a solution for it The project does not even build due to the following error;

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages;

I am using Eclipse Indigo and JDK 1.6 compiler.

Please help.

Comment: try see that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: Tank you for responding...i tried but none of those helped :(

Comment: add your one jar file in libs folder and add your another jar file as a external jar file.

Answer (score 0):

> > Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages;

This error Message means, you have more then one file named "define" in your Project.

In your case check Project scr Directory:

org/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages

There should be a file named "define" (define.java).

Check the others scr Directorys if there a additional "define" file.

If yes, delete one of this "define" files.

If not delete "define" in

org/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages

Then clean your Project.

That it was.