# Button to Facebook Login

Tags: android

I am Beginner in android.
I want to create a app to fetch facebook friends birthday.
I have created a home page where I have added the button.
I want a code to click on button and that will lead me to facebook login.After Login I can fetch my friends birthdays..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the facebook sdk: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Comment: Thnx..I did that..But Now after completing my coding..When I am trying to run my application it shows this error :

Comment: [2013-06-21 17:03:15 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$SerializationProxyV1;
[2013-06-21 17:03:15 - MyFirstApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$SerializationProxyV1;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray