# Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am getting this error while i am compiling my project.

I am using drive-api services in the app.
can anybody tell me that why it is happning.

Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/auth/jsontoken/JsonWebToken$Header;
[2013-06-28 15:17:23 - NotesList] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/auth/jsontoken/JsonWebToken$Header;

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Hope it helps

Comment: i allready checked all the questions, but can't found any solution. i am adding drive api v2 , and it is including many zar files in to the project i think that was causing the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray/7884908#7884908 check this.