# MultipartEntity entity

Tags: android, dex, multipartentity

after update Android SDK 22.0.5 I can not compile my project.
I get the error message:

```
 Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/auth/AUTH;
```

If I delete the Libarys mime4j apache-core-0.7.2.jar, httpclient-4.2.2.jar, core-4.2.2.jar and http http mime-4.2.2.jar and I commented out the code to compile the code.

I need to upload MultipartEntity.

Any ideas what I can do?

Thanks for help

Comment: This looks very similar to this other problem that has a solution noted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: Yes i have read this befor. But this dont help me "I finally discovered that my bin directory was included in the project build path. I excluded bin from the build path and repeated the steps above. This resolved my problem."