# Unable to execute dex: compiler error

Tags: java, android

I have android project and I added this jar file: "mahout-math-0.5"
and when I try to run android application I get the next error:

> [2013-10-09 14:13:50 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex
> files define Lorg/apache/mahout/math/function/DoubleFunction;
>
> [2013-10-09 14:13:50 - DargAndDrop] Conversion to Dalvik format
> failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
> Lorg/apache/mahout/math/function/DoubleFunction;

I am understand that the problem is have two dex files in my project but how I can remove one of them
I see answers of others people but I can not carry them in my project
thank you every body

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: open bin->dexedLibs you will find multiple jar files delete them and include your jar again but remember that you should not include same jar two times or including the jar from Path built and also coping jar in libs

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the quick reply
I tried both options and they did not help me
Is there anything else I can do? I have to use this file