# how to fix Android Error Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La$1

Tags: java, android

hi I am new in this Error it showing Error when i run our Android application (Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La$1)

Earlier this was running Perfectly But sudden application containing Error not able to run our application .

This is Error coming In Our console :

```
[2014-01-06 13:47:28 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La$1;
[2014-01-06 13:47:28 - Taxmann - Android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La$1;
```

please tell me how i will fix this Error I found this Error first time please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error before when I use Zxing library.

Now I can explain what I did and how I fix this.

I have imported zxing library into my project and also imported one lib(called GZxing) that contains within zxing library. When I run application I have same error as you.

Solution:

I deleted zxing library and keep only GZxing library and it works fine.

I assume you could have some  class or files that already exist on your project.

Answer (score 0):

2 or more jar files may contain same class and methods. so getting this kind of error, to resolve it need to remove common jar files which contain same class details. and make project clean and run again.this may helps you.