# Persistent No Class Def Found Error and external JAR issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, wordnet

My code reads

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import rita.wordnet.RiWordnet;
import java.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView strlab;
    strlab=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
    String word = "diode";
    System.out.println("\nFinding parts of speech for " + word + ".");
    String[] partsofspeech = wordnet.getPos(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < partsofspeech.length; i++) {
        strlab.setText(""+partsofspeech[i]);            
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

It compiles fine. I'm using the latest version of the Android SDK ADT bundle for windows available. When ever i run the app it stops unexpectedly.

I'm using RITA Wordnet jar files. I added them by simply copying them to libs folder.

I understand the jar files needs java 5.0 or 6.0. So I changed the setting to 1.6 in the Java compiler options in the project properties. I also understand the "order and export" method of adding jars is out-dated.

Can someone please help me ?

Edit:
Adding screenshots of my log cat

[image]

[image]

Comment: are the jar files in the build path?

Comment: @Sionnach733 yes they are in the build path . they are listed under "android private libraries" in the "java build path" tab of project properties .

Comment: Where is the RiWordnet class in the import section of your Activity?

Comment: @edubriguenti Sorry the two import files got truncated when i was posting. edited the question. but the problem remains :(

Comment: try this : right click on project name -> build path ->android -> add external jars -> then select it and then again give it a try.

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh , when a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown, normally the class that was not found is printed on the console as well. What class is it complaining about?

Comment: @wqrahd No that didn't work either :(

Comment: @edubriguenti I've posted my log cat just before the app terminated.

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace above, it seems you need more dependencies. In your case the **Java WordNet Library**.

**http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jwordnet/jwnl**

Do you have this one inside your classpath?

Comment: But when compiled as a stand alone Java application in Eclipse it works fine and produces the desired output!. Download the JWNL jar and adding it to libs results in


"[2014-02-06 15:41:32 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lnet/didion/jwnl/JWNL$OS;

[2014-02-06 15:41:32 - Dtester] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lnet/didion/jwnl/JWNL$OS;"

Comment: Try to do this for this last problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: It seems this last problem is caused when you have more versions of the same class in your classpath.

Comment: yes I checked. nothing has been included twice. cleaned and fixed the class path twice :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Poject Explorer` in Eclipse then select `Property->Java Build Path ->Order and Export` then checked  only tick marks  on `Android Private Libraries` and `Android Dependencies` and unchecked all jar files there if it was checked before.Tell us if it is working or not.