# Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazon/ags/BuildConfig when using GameCircleSDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently imported my Android project from Eclipse into AndroidStudio. Everything went fairly well, and I was able to resolve most issues, except when it came down to the GameCircleSDK library module. I kept getting the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazon/ags/BuildConfig;
```

As it turns out, the **com.amazon.ags.BuildConfig.class** was indeed contained in two jars: **classes.jar** (which got generated during the build) and **GameCircleSDK/libs/gamecirclesdk.jar**.

The only way I could solve the issue was to unzip the *gamecirclesdk.jar*, remove the `BuildConfig.class`, and zip it back up again. I searched the internets for a solution, and I tried just about everything listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray), but nothing seemed to resolve my situation. Am I missing something?

Comment: You'll need to attach your build files to the question to get a better answer. It's not clear what this classes.jar is that got generated during the build, and why it's including that class.

Comment: The GameCricleSDK library is part of the [Amazon Mobile App SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk), it is not my code. Apparently nobody is trying to use this library in Android Studio...

Comment: I'm an Amazon developer in the games division working on Android. I don't work on the GameCircle team, but I'm going to pass along this issue to them.

Comment: Thanks for passing this along @SomeCallMeTim!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that GameCricleSDK.jar contains BuildConfig file with package name "com.amazon.ags" and the whole module is also generating BuildConfig file with the same package name as declared in Manifest. I changed the package name in module Manifest file and problem went away.

SOLUTION:
Take the GameCircleSDK library, open it's AndroidManifest.xml and change the packageName from "com.amazon.ags" to sth else no matter what. I changed it to "com.amazon.ags.lib".

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in responding, but can you please provide more detail? Which manifest did you change?

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it's understandable now ;)

Comment: Thanks, I looked through AndroidManifest.xml files in my library modules, and found the same package name which I wrongly used for a new module

Comment: @mar3kk after changing the package name, it is ok in debug build but I suffer  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError  on the release build

Comment: Hmm first I would check if proguard is enabled and if it is I would disable it or change rules to keep the class which is missing

Comment: Changing the package name in the manifest prevent the class inside the library project to use the `res`present in the library project. This is not a solution whera library project is used because it's not possible to add `res` in a jar

Comment: This was not the cause of the issue in my case, rather I  had gamecirclesdk.jar both in my Library project's lib folder and my main project's lib folder. Please check for multiple gamecirclesdk.jar in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using a different library project though(WeiboSDK). You may also need to change the applicationId in the library's build.gradle file to the same value in the library's AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: AFAiK You cannot set applicationId in library module anymore using recent android gradle plugin.