# Java Apache Mina FTP Server import libraries

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-mina

I want to create an Android FTP Server App with the Apache Mina FTP Server.

The problem is the following: I can't import these libraries.

I can select between two errors:

If the libs aren't selected in "Java Build Path"/"Order and Export", I get this error:

```
"Could not find class 'org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory' (...)" 

(Logcat)
```

If they are selected, I get this error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: 
Unable to execute dex: 
Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/ftpserver/ftplet/FtpException;

(Problems / Errors)
```

What's wrong??

My imported libraries:

- ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar
- ftpserver-core-1.0.6.jar
- mina-core-2.0.4.jar (or 2.0.7)
- slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar (or 1.6.6)
- slf4j-simple-1.5.3.jar

Comment: What can I do? I didn't solve the problem yet..

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: Thanks for the link but none of these many tips could help me..

Comment: ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar
ftpserver-core-1.0.6.jar 
Are these two supposed to be used in the same project?

Comment: Yes, I used the files listed in the tutorial [mina.apache.org](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html)

Comment: Haven't programmed in android, but maybe this `ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar` is already available? Remove it and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue with any android project when I add jCenter dependency on *org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:1.0.6*. Project compiles successfully, but it fails when I try to start it.

I realized, that ftpserver-core-1.0.6.jar contains classes from ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar.

To fix the issue, I used local libraries, but deleted  ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar. I am not sure that it is totally correct solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had the same problem and this fix worked for me too.
What I did was to exclude the ftplet-api-1.0.6 in my build.gradle:
    `dependencies {
        ...
        compile('org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:1.0.6') {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.ftpserver', module: 'ftplet-api'
        }
        ...
    }`