# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/andengine/AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, dalvik, dex

I'm getting this error when running my project:

```
[2014-05-21 20:42:51 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/andengine/AndEngine;
[2014-05-21 20:42:51 - MyActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/andengine/AndEngine;
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16606378/2987421

Comment: I've tried ! This solution was not :(

Comment: You have tried all variants from that linked post and nothing worked?

Comment: I've tried almost every way , but I could not find the solution PLEASE HELP ME !!

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the same class is contained in your project several times, usually through dependencies. Make sure to check that none of the used libraries overlap.

Comment: I use a lot of libraries.I do not understand what you mean. (I'm sorry :( I know very little English)

Comment: I can't help you without more information about the libraries you use and how you set them up.

Comment: Thanks StackOverflowException.
I'm using these libraries :
AndEngine
AndEngine GLES2 AnchorCenter
AndEngineAugementedRealityExtension
AndEngineDebugDrawExtension
AndEngineExamples
AndEngineLiveWalpaperExtension
AndEngineMODPlayerExtension
AndEngineMultiplayerExtension
AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension
AndEngineScriptingExtension
AndEngineSVGTextureRegionExtension
AndEngineTexturePackerExtension
AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension

Comment: This doesn't help, as you set them up the wrong way. You need to figure out which of these libraries contain the class `org.andengine.AndEngine`. There must be more than one of these libraries that contain this class, but you may only include it once.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using the same library multiple class. So right click your project, click **Properties**, then click **Android** from left. Look at Library section, if you see AndEngine multiple times, remove one.

*Muhtemelen AndEngine kütüphanesini aynı projede birden fazla yerde kullanıyorsun. Projene sağ tıkla, **Properties**'i seç, soldan **Android**'e tıkla. Aşağıda Library bölümünde eğer birden fazla AndEngine ile başlayan şey varsa bir tane hariç diğerlerini tek tek Remove'a basarak sil. Eğer zaten bir tane varsa, soldan **Java Build Path**'e tıkladıktan sonra sağdan **Order and Export**'a bas. andengine.jar gibi bir dosya varsa soldan tikini kaldır. OK'e basıp çık ve dene, işe yaramazsa Project -> Clean yap. O da işe yaramazsa Java Build Path -> Libraries altındaki kütüphanelerin isimlerini söyle.*

Comment: Teşekkurler.soylediklerinizi yaptm fakat ayni hatayla tekrar karsilastm.butun kutuphaneleri kaldirdim sadece uc tane kaldi.onlarda kullanmak zorunda oldugum kutuphaneler.andenginegles2-anchorcenter.jar ve andenginephysicsbox2Dextension.jar ve andengine.jar Lutfen baska bir yontem varsa yardimci olun.gercekten bu hata karsisinda ne yapacagimi sasirdim :(

Comment: **andenginegles2-anchorcenter.jar** ve **andengine.jar** aynı kütüphanenin farklı versiyonları. AndEngine'in GLES2-AnchorCenter  versiyonunu kullanıyorsanız **andengine.jar**'ı kaldırın. GLES2 veya GLES1 versiyonunu kullanıyorsanız **andenginegles2-anchorcenter.jar**'ı kaldırın.

Comment: Yardımlarınız için çok teşekkürler fakat bu da işe yaramadı :( yani andengine.jar ' ı kaldırdım ama aynı hatayı tekrar aldım şu an sadece andenginegles2-anchorcenter.jar ve andenginephysicsbox2Dextension.jar kütüphaneleri kaldı. karşıma çıkan neredeyse her yöntemi denedim fakat bir türlü olmadı.Önerebileceğiniz başka bir yol var mıdır acacba?