# Error in android running the project "Multiple dex"

Tags: android

Error message from console and please fix the project also
[image]

```
014-07-03 19:09:15 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle;
[2014-07-03 19:09:15 - RSExample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle;
```

I did all circus like refresh,clean checking jar files.............but I found no result these code has been taken from the github.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: i completed all this aqctivity before and i remove some unessery jar files also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.find the error class

2.check out that the class is available in how many jar(definitely that  )

3.if available both, remove one jar

4.run

Note : becoz of two classes are trying to execute , then the problem occur

or check the java buldpath

[image]