# Facing issue while intergrating retrofit with cordova

Tags: cordova

I am trying to use third party library retrofit for network calls in cordova (Phonegap 3.5.0), As cordova is already having same classes with in it causing conflict between cordova and retrofit at run time. 
So when i tried building APK i am getting the following stack trace.Please any one help me how to come out from this issue.Thanks in advance for reply

---

```
[2014-07-09 12:25:32 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HeaderParser;
[2014-07-09 12:25:32 - PluginTest] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HeaderParser;
```

Comment: Does this offer you any help [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: They are using OkHttp 1.3 also in 4.0.0 [cordova-repo-3.5](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/3.5.x/framework/src/com/squareup/okhttp) :(

Comment: I found an open bug about this: [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6630)