# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android

Whats worng ?why i have this problems?

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
```

and

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using android library (another library project) that has the a .jar library named the same as another .jar in your project but with different sha1 (or different sizes) ?

if so try to use only 1 of the duplicated library and then clean and rebuild.

also check this question it may be helpful [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)