# How to build differents APK with the same source code? (I'm getting error)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, apk

I need to build a custom APKs from a base source code. I've marked my base project as a library, and then I've created a new project with the main project referenced.
But when I build the new project I'm getting an error.

```
[2014-09-15 09:41:15 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/example/libswipe/R$anim;
[2014-09-15 09:41:15 - A3] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/example/libswipe/R$anim;
```

My main project has a referenced library named libswipe, but I dont know why I'm getting this error, because I'm not referencing that library again in the new custom project.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: @Opiatefuchs this didn't solved my problem, but thanks anyway