# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat

Tags: android

I am getting below exception when I try to run my project:

```
[2014-09-29 11:56:32 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
[2014-09-29 11:56:32 - PageViewers] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
```

Comment: You are using library project with your main project..if this is the case then you have to use same jar in both the projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: A quick google search with your error message gave me that link...

Comment: Run gradle -q dependencies to generate a dependency report. You should see where v7 is coming from and also  post your gradle file

Comment: please , check my answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

**you have twice compat library**

So, how I solved this problem:

1. Import support library as a project from
   "sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat".
2. Reference library in your project (for Eclipse, "Properties -
   Android - Add").
3. Build projects (for Eclipse, "Projects - Build All"). Make sure, you
   have "android.support.v7.appcompat" in your main project gen
       folder.
4. If it doesn't worked - clean and rebuild project.

Comment: it works.

Make sure, you have "android.support.v7.appcompat" in your main project gen folder.

Helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot but finally I solved it by executing

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

refer github [issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/241).