# Console error. Unable to execute dex?

Tags: android, eclipse

Please can anyone tel me how to solve the below posted error? despite the App has no errors, i receive that error when i try to launch it.

**Console_Error**

```
[2014-11-06 13:04:49 - org.eclipse.paho.android.service.test] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-11-06 13:04:49 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define   
Lorg/eclipse/paho/android/service/AlarmPingSender$AlarmReceiver$1;
[2014-11-06 13:04:49 - org.eclipse.paho.android.service.test] Conversion to Dalvik format failed:   
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define   
Lorg/eclipse/paho/android/service/AlarmPingSender$AlarmReceiver$1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Right click on the Project Name
Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Java Build Path, go to the tab Order and Export

Uncheck your .jar library
```

Only sometimes: In Order and Export tab I did not have any jar library there, so I have unchecked 
   Android Private Libraries item. Now my project is running.

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using both jar file and SDK of third party library. Delete jar from libs folder or remove that SDK from your project

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, but i need these jars in the project, if i deleted them how can i run he project

Comment: Are you using SDK of this library too??

Comment: i guess there may be duplicate jar file in libs folder