# Android NoClassDefFoundError NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, notifications

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder`

I know this error is resolved by adding private libraries to project, but in my case if I add private libraries then I am getting different error:

`Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define`

And the fix for above was removing private libraries which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

So any better solution???

My code:

```
private void check() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext());
    Notification notification = builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("New notification")
            .setContentText("Hello world!").build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

My project build path :

[image]

Comment: There are some people, they are down voting bcz of they are eligible for that, be professional.If down voting give the reason as comment then only the user can find the mistake and do good next time.

Comment: Feel like punching on their face.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added two similar libraries to your project .
Go to project properties ->java Build Path->libraries

Comment: Please check my build path screenshot. I haven't added.

Comment: please show me libraries (beside order and export)screenshot.