# Why we get Multiple dex files define error in android

Tags: java, android, jar

I am creating a jar file where i did right click on project name then `export>java>Jar file` and then i checked on `export generated class files and resources` by selecting only src folder files and classpath and .project file.

This jar file i tried to use in another android project and i am getting this above

> `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define com/example/projectname/xyzClass`

So i followed this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) and unchecked my jar in order and export of buildpath and if i do so i am getting another error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.xyzClass`

I have no idea why i am getting `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define' error.

And here is the screenshot of order and export of my project where i am using my servicedemonew2.jar file.[image]

I would be glad if someone assist me with this why and when do we get this above error.

Comment: Must sure that your `Android Private Libraries` checkbox will be checked in `Order and Export menu`.Show your manifest too

Comment: Ya it is checked Piyush.

Comment: Uncheck Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies checkbox

Comment: I unchecked it and i am getting that NoClassDefFoundError error.

Answer (score 0):

After seen your screenshot you need to uncheck your `Android Dependencies` and `servicedemonew2.jar` checkbox. `Android Private Libraries` will be remain checkable.

Comment: No need to `<h1>Solution:</h1>` as an answer should contain a possible solution which would make it redundant. A good programmer prevents redundancy!

Comment: Piyush still i haven't found a solution. If i uncheck those two then i am getting NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Comment: Is Android Private Libraries checked??

Comment: Yes it is checked as you said.

Comment: Strange before some day i got same issue and solved this way. Do one thing just uncheck Android Dependencies and other both will checkable. And finally clean your project and run it

Comment: I tried adding the servicedemonew2.jar in libs folder also and checked private libraries and servicedemonew2.jar in order and export and tried and i am getting Unable to exec: Multiple dex file error. And if i delete jar from libs folder and try same then i get NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65690/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-naveen-kumar).