# Eclipse project is not running

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Yesterday all of my projects were working but today they are not. Also Eclipse doesn't show any errors on these projects. I plug my device and click run button it tries to run the project a few seconds then says there are errors and you should fix them. But It doesn't shows any errors. I tried to download Android 5.0 yesterday but cancelled it . Is this may caused this ? Does anyone knows how to fix it ?

[image]

```
[2014-12-03 23:57:24 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define android/support/annotation/AnimRes;
[2014-12-03 23:57:24 - 17.11.2014] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

I'm seeing these errors on log. Does anyone knows what does Dalvik format failed means ??

Comment: Can you post more specific information on what the errors are? It could be a variety of things since the problem could be with your java setup, your android setup, or your eclipse setup.

Comment: There are no errors!! thats my problem eclipse says I have problems on my project but doesn't show them. The project I'm trying to run is above. As you can see it has no errors just some warnings about hardcoded strings. I've mistakely changed some libs files on my desktop but I've fixed them later by build path..

Comment: Right so eclipse has a 'markers' view (Window > Show View > Markers) that should have something in it if eclipse is saying that there are errors. I'd look there and try doing a project clean, refresh and rebuild.

Comment: I've did it . nothing has changed. still looks like everything fine but doesn't run ...

Comment: Maybe its time to move to Android Studio.

Comment: Too right.. I've moved yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu Project->Clean and clean your project. May be it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've understand the problem. It's already answered under this question [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)