# Error while using Parse SDK for tesiting PUSH Notifications-Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1

Tags: android, parse-platform

`{Dex Loader} Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1`;

I keep getting this error while exporting my project in `Eclipse`.
I have tried all the solutions mentioned in similar questions but yet it's not working..
Already tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray).

Comment: try to clean the project

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just delete FaceBook jar **ParseFacebookUtils V3**

it makes conflict with **ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar**

and It will be Run

Comment: For those that are experiencing the issue but this isn't the issue, use the search icon and search for the class causing you issues. It should then show you if you have any files hidden anywhere

Answer (score 8):

Delete the V3 jar file in your projects lib file ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.9.1.jar. Which conflicts V4, ParseFacebookUtilsV4...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to go to you folder bin/dexedLibs and delete the folders and the files where the name is using V3 or V4

For example
ParseFacebookUtilisV3-1.9.0.jar.pro

And after that go to the folder libs and delete the files with the same words incluted in the name

This files and folders are an extra extension.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with Parse's Android Anywall example project. I had duplicate android dependencies for Parse:

```
compile ('com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+')
compile ('com.parse:parse-android:1.+')       /* <-- removed this */
```