# Build gradle map box and google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, mapbox

In my android application, I have a function that works with GCM
and I use google_play_services_lib.

Now I am implementing MapBox maps, no Google maps.

I did various tests in a separate project with MapBox and perfect,
but when I compile both dependencies, the applicattion not runs.

I think my problem is of dependencies between
google play services and map box.

Here is my script and my log.
I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "storecheck.com.storecheck2"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:0.7.1@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
}
```

Log

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMapboxMapboxsdkMapboxAndroidSdk071Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2.
```

Well, My project is in Android Studio. 
I tried in Eclipse, and I downloaded source code of MapBox and all dependencies. But, the project no compile  .

Shows errors as

"[2015-04-15 11:28:26 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/almeros/android/multitouch/TwoFingerGestureDetector;"

Researching, I found this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18177694/3814000

And in the comments says:

"This error can happen if you have two jars that contains the same class names, e.g. I had two library: jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar, and jersey-core-1.17.1.jar, both containing the class javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath. I removed jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar and it worked fine."

I think that the google play services lib and map box has this problem.

But I am not sure

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: I Put the  multiDexEnabled = true, but, my problem continues. I think is a problem with the  jars with the same name class [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18177694/3814000)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In mi project I use only gcm.

Then, only compile this library.

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'

Works fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Mapbox Android SDK does not require Google Play Services as a dependency.  Unless other parts of the implementing app make use of it, it can safely be removed to make the app smaller.