# Android - is it possible to Ignore duplicated dex files?

Tags: java, android

My program is generating duplicate .dex files and I am unsure why this is happening. The console output is as follows:

```
[2015-09-05 18:49:47 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/googlecode/android_scripting/Analytics$1;
[2015-09-05 18:49:47 - SensibilityTestbed2] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/googlecode/android_scripting/Analytics$1;
```

And after every attempt to run the program, the files get duplicated once again; they look like:

```
ScriptActivity$1.class, ScriptActivity$2.class, ScriptActivity$3.class...etc
```

I have tried just about every single combination from previous SO posts, including but not limited to:

- Unchecking different library dependencies in the Java Build Path.
- Deleting duplicate .jar files.

But to no avail, so I was wondering if there is a way to make the compiler completely ignore these duplicate .dex files? I am working with Eclipse.

Comment: Erm ... how would the compiler know which one to ignore??  Wrong approach.  Find out why the duplicates are being generated and fix it so that it doesn't happen.

Comment: It is not complaining that there are `ScriptActivity$1.class`, `ScriptActivity$2.class`, etc.  Those are not duplicates.  They are different anonymous inner classes defined in `ScriptActivity.java`.  It is complaining that it can find two or more DEX files that match the `ScriptActivity$1.class` file.

Comment: Hi @StephenC, I was wondering if you could please point me in the right direction... Where am I supposed to look for that? I've been at it for a couple of days, it feels like I'm looking for a needle in a haystack... If you could please provide some debugging tips for this problem I would really appreciate it

Comment: We for a start ... you should be looking for duplicate "dex" files in the filesystem.

Comment: Also check out this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray