# Android - Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem when compiling my project, I get the error `Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'`. 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Diana\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Diana\Downloads\VoiceTranslator\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Diana\Downloads\VoiceTranslator\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

I know this question has been asked many times but I have tried the solutions from there and none of them works in my case.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "imp.translator.diana.voicetranslator"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here? Any tip would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Have your tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: @buzeeg yes, it doesn't work

Comment: invalidate cache and restart the android studio...then try with rebuilding the project

Comment: @ShadowDroid I have tried it now, doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'libs/android-support-v4.jar'` from `compile files(...)`. This file is a transitive dependency of appcompat-v7 library.