# facebook Multiple dex files define without excluding support-v4

Tags: android, facebook

is there another solution for the "Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes" error using Facebook SDK for android, besides excluding group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'4 in build.graddle?

When I do this, another SDK, for another service that I use, fails and shows me: "error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.actionbaroverlaylayout"

So, can somebody point me to another workaround so I don't have to exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' and that way I can use another SDK that I need too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15462749/812598) solution? Otherwise try the most voted one of that thread, this must be your solution for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the jar for support-v4 from facebook and added it like this  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+' in facebook's graddle script and in the main one.