# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;

Tags: android, eclipse, dex

```
[2015-10-14 17:48:05 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;
[2015-10-14 17:48:05 - MyApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;
```

I know this happens because my two jar files contains the same class `Base64`. But they are two entirely different jar files, one is `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.3.6.jar` and other is `indooratlas-android-sdk-1.4.2-132-beta.jar`.

And I need to use both the libraries as it is and need avoid the above error. hope someone can help me.

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) and almost all related links.

**FACT**

I don't think it as duplicate of above mentioned question, because I am in search to recover from this error in a possible new way.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution for this is to use the [HttpClient port for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

> **Differences with the stock version of Apache HttpClient**
>   ..
>   3. Base64 implementation from Commons Codec replaced with Android Base64.

HttpClient won't include commons-codec's Base64, and your app will not have multiple definitions of Base64 class.

Additionally, since you're including the `commons-codec` library in your application make sure to read [my blogpost](http://blog.osom.info/2015/04/commons-codec-on-android.html) in order to prevent potential unexpected behaviour (more specifically, runtime crashes).

Comment: I have removed the Base64 class from one my .JAR files, and now it work like a charm. Thank you for your responses.