# How to solve the issue Unable to execute dex

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

I am using eclipse. When i am adding facebook library give error  "Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: No it is not usefull for me

Answer (score 0):

you are passing maximum limit of functions count , one way might be using `multidex` , another might be excluding some libraries from `Google play services` if you are using that.

except importing whole google play service library features, import what you need separately like :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

Comment: Yes i am using Google play services lib.

Comment: I am using in app purchase then how to import separately please guide me

Comment: i think on google play services above version 6.5 , you can import google play features separately.