# Multiple dex files define Lcom/coremedia/iso/AbstractBoxParser$1;

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I got a `Gradle` Error:

> Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define Lcom/coremedia/iso/AbstractBoxParser$1;I
>   want to used both isoparser-1.0.6.jar and compile
>   'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.+'

for my development purpose.My Gradle given below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'

    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.+'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

    compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: Remove the JAR files. Use actual Maven targets.

Comment: Actuly i am first compress video so used JAR and then Trim or cut video  so used  'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.+'.If i remove JAR so  compress after video sound was effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Multiple dex files define L**com/coremedia/iso/**

You don't need the JAR files. The fact that you are using them is causing duplicate files, which Gradle can resolve on its own, but only when using Maven dependencies.

You compiled this ISO parser library already . And it depends on aspectjrt, so you don't need to explicitly compile that unless you really want to

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.mp4parser/isoparser/1.0.6

```
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.2' // This version is used by isoparser:1.0.6

// compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
// compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
```

You need to actually **delete** the JAR files because this line will compile them anyway. In other words, putting `compile files()` was redundant

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: If i remove JAR so compress after video sound was effected.

Comment: Actually i am used two lib in my project.One is for Video compress(https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor) and other is for video trim (https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer).When I marge two code in my Project it show  Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/coremedia/iso/AbstractBoxParser$1 in my gradle.I remove JAR and Run the Project it was effect Compress video sound(Video play with out sound).