# Barcode scanner with ZXing library

Tags: android, zxing

I am developeing a barcode app. in which captured barcode camera image are decode through ZXing library. so simply i have download jar file and add it as external jar. but my problem is that how can i start use of that class there are no sample code at all. so can you provide me some initial thing so i can easily go through that process.

Comment: I made code for barcode generate and scan barcode. 

You can follow this to get the Step By Step Code.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742737/11613683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to  call the ZXing SCAN Intent from your application, like this:

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}

Ref:http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Sample code:http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-barcode-scanner-using-zxing.html
```

Comment: i know this but can you tell me, is it only way that continue with intent. can we use class of zXing ? and if yes that how can we start?

Comment: so can you tell me which thing reqired in device which is get responce of intent

Comment: I made code for barcode generate and scan barcode. 

You can follow this  to get the Step By Step Code.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742737/11613683

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Just go through the Zxing library source link, and look at [**Android-Integration**](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid-integration%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fintegration%2Fandroid) part in which you can find how to use **Android-Zxing** library.

Comment: Look at example [Integrate zxing barcode scanner into your Android app natively using Eclipse](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/)

Comment: I made code for barcode generate and scan barcode. 

You can follow this to get the Step By Step Code.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742737/11613683

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use intent method, you can use few classes of ZXing directly in your project.

I did the same following these 2 stackoverflow posts

[How to use zxing core as library on my Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002845/how-to-use-zxing-core-as-library-on-my-andorid-project)

[Embedding ZXing in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969679/yet-another-question-about-embedding-zxing-in-android-app)

After copying the basic classes, you can strip down parts of code of the class CaptureActivity.java (this is the main activity class) by trial and error method.

Answer (score 0):

My way was to import the code into a helloworld, get it working and then play around it by importing this as a subproject. I have also uploaded this hello world project to 4shared. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276635/how-to-include-and-use-zxing-library-in-android-with-eclipse/9108983#9108983).