# Barcode scanner in android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am developing an barcode scanning application using zxing(in eclipse). I have read many stack overflow threads about developing. 
I saw mostly things like, need to use a barcode scanner app for handling the decoding the barcodes and QR-codes.

Is there any option to do that also using the code like capturing the image using camera and then read? We need to create an independent app. Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance and expecting a detailed reply if possible.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest advantages of the Android platform is that you can leverage other apps to provide increased usefulness for yours without a ton of work. In essence yes you could rewrite the bar-code app, but a lot of people will ask why would you want to reinvent the wheel? Now it is true that the zxing process is open source so you can look at their entire program, however I found it more effective to just leverage what was already there.

If you place a check in the program to see if the system can handle the action, you can recommend people get the bar-code scanner to unlock that functionality.

This process is encouraged by the folks at Google. However, as always, you can always try to rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: thanks @pyrodante. for the quick reply and sorry for my bad english. I have tried to load the image from sd card and then decode. Actually its working fine. Instead can i read the image that its captured by camera and decode it? I am lacking in this part only. Please provide any links or steps to continue the process.

Comment: Here is a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app

Comment: Thanks for referring this link @Pyrodante. I need to implement a stand-alone app. So i have to do via intents. I saw the code in \android\ directory in zxing src i downloaded. I compiled the barcode scanning app source code and tested it in device. Its working fine. Question thats what i want to ask is, for invoking the CaptureActivity in src, i need the other activities? How can i seperate the scanning part only to implement the same using the zxing libraries. Or do i need the whole source files in the **/android/** directory to build a scanning module? thanks for helping :)