# How to build android project to JAR file?

Tags: android, build, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app)

- I need to integrate Zxing barcode android project to other project, so I need to build to Zxing barcode android project to JAR file, 
  so does it possible to that?

or what the best way to integrate Android project to other project?

Answer (score 0):

First download ZXing-1.7.zip from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list.Extract it into your C Drive. Then open the android project inside extracted folder using eclipse IDE.
On the first time its showing library missing error.To fix, first create a src folder in your project.Right click on the newly created folder and select import , choose from the disk and choose the core folder in the extracted folder to import the core libraries into the project.Finally you need to clean the project.