# What is a better and easy way to integrate QR code scanning in android application

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I have read about zxing library but have no experience on that, also is this possible to use inbuilt or installed barcode reader in my application..

Any one having any experience on this please can guide me step by step.

lots of thanks

Comment: Yes you can use zxing library in your application if you know programming...

Comment: do you mean Zxing will be a better approach to use? and I know android development but have no experience on implementing application for barcode scanning :)

Comment: Have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2051953/786914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy. [Here is how you integrate by Intent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).