# android zxing QR code generation

Tags: android, zxing

I want to generate a QR code of a simple text with zxing library but I could not find any library or API for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Zxing api for bar scanner and generator

here is a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app) also [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

[Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en) this app is based on Zxing api.
You can use all functionality.

Comment: this is for scan n i want for generation and do you know from where to get core.java for zxing?

Comment: I m using it for both generating and also for scanning, it also support linear and pdf codes.

Comment: from where you got core.java please give me link

Comment: [core](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-2.0.zip&can=2&q=) download it and go for "zxing-2.0\core", there is also new update, updated in october but I use before.

Comment: will you please show me wt code you used for code generation?i uesd intentintegrator.java and intentresult.java but having error.

Comment: Using of these is a simple way to invoke barcode scanning and receive the result, without any need to integrate, modify library code. carefully read them you will got them.

Answer (score 1):

The `IntentIntegrator` method relies on having the Barcode Scanner app installed.

If you don't want to install a third party application you can use the ZXing library and make your app a standalone app.  Just follow [this step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510698/1181911).