# Distributing the ZXing APK file with my app

Tags: android, integration, zxing, barcode-scanner

I wish to use the ZXing barcode scanner app along with my app and their site recommends "distributing the project's release, rather than building from source, for best user experience".
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

I've searched and searched and haven't come across a way to have one's own APK file in Google Play and have someone else's APK be loaded along with it when a user installs my app.

Has anyone had any experience doing this with an APK or more specifically the ZXing Barcode Scanner?

I know I can prompt the user midstream to download the app but that is not ideal for the user experience I'm interested in offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant deploy a second apk with your apk as far as I know. The best you can do is make the acquisition of the 3rd party app you want to send intents to as smooth as possible.

For instance when the user hits the button with the intention of scanning search for the zxing package and if not found redirect the user to download zxing from the playstore.

[Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app)

Comment: Thanks!  I think I'm unfortunately going to have to embed the ZXing code inside my app to achieve what is being requested of me.  I've seen some posts that show it's possible, though probably not the ideal solution.

Comment: The linked post does provide some ideas for port libraries. I know in xamarin there is a component that provides a library or api for using zxing so I am sure there is something in Java for accomplishing the same level of integration.