# How can I use a scanner library and scan in the background of the my android app using an embedded scanner?

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I have a Honeywell Dolphin 70e and it has physical buttons to trigger the scanning. I can create a listener for those buttons, and use ZXing to scan. However the scanner has an embedded laser scanner so I would like the app to stay on the same page, rather than switching to another screen (assuming it is ZXing that is showing this page). The other thing is that I would like the scanner to be on when the button is pressed, and if the button is released, then the scanner would turn off.

The device comes with a scanning demo application that has these features, but I cannot find anything on the Honeywell website. Any help would be much appreciated!

Below is the honeywell website with some documentation and sample code in the SDK for Windows. Below that is a stackoverflow question with the same as what Honeywell provides.

http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-mobile-computer&cat=HSM&pid=dolphin70e

[Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found on the Honeywell knowledge base that under Power Tools --> ScanWedge there is an enable/disable. When ScanWedge is enabled the scanner buttons work as expected in any application (basically just keyboard input). Thanks for the replies!

Comment: That's great @Elmer!

Answer (score 0):

- So, I think https://developers.google.com/vision/ can replace for ZXing. You can custom anything you want.

Comment: I looked into google vision and will definitely look into it for other features. Thanks!